# How can i change an inline css style when clicking a link?

Tags: html, css, styles

i have a form hidden with inline `style="display: none;"`

how can i dinamicaly change this style to `style="display: inline;"` when a link on the page is clicked?

Comment: You're gonna need JavaScript.

Comment: oh, ok, doing that now.. sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prety simple

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').style.display = 'inline';">Click me</a>
```

#### Update

---

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) is a lightweight JavaScript library that can do tons of cool stuff, with writing a very less script from the developers side.

First of all, I suggest you to read "[How jQuery  works?](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)", is has everything you need to get started using the jQuery.

---

I will explain the code I  wrote in the fiddle.

First of all the link & form

```
<a id="linktotoggle" href="#">Click Me</a>
<form id="formtotoggle"></form>
```

Remember the id in the link and form above. That is how we are going to select the element in the script just like what `document.getElementById()` does.

Lets hide the form by default

```
#formtotoggle { display: none; }
```

Now lets write the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// ^ This is an event, which triggers once all the document is loaded so that the manipulation is always guaranteed to run.
   $("#linktotoggle").click(function() {
   // ^ Attach a click event to our link
        $("#formtotoggle").toggle();
        // ^ select the form and toggle its display

   });
});
```

Hope it is enough, to get you started.

Comment: it shows the form when i click but does not hide the form when i click again.

Comment: @LucasMatos, display `inline` does not hide the form. use `display = 'none'` to do so

Comment: @LucasMatos, let me guess, you want to hide and unhide the form onclick to the button

Comment: @LucasMatos, I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/XqZgL/) using jquery. Hope it helps

Comment: thats what i need, but can you pls tell me how can i create this jquery function? its like javascript or what?

Comment: @LucasMatos, I am sorry, I was out. jQuery is javascript library. That eases up a lot of things you could do using javascript. I will update my answer, to make you understand a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an `onclick` event on the anchor, and set the form style to `display:block`, here's a js fiddle to help you going

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUgPv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find some way of selecting the form using JavaScript, first; here's a function assuming that your form has an `id` attribute of `myform`:

```
function showForm() {
    document.getElementById('myform').style.display = 'inline';
}
```

Then, just bind that function to your link's `click` event. A quick and dirty way is to set the link's `onclick` attribute to `showForm(); return false`, but you'll probably want to do that in external JavaScript to separate your content and behaviour nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check this JQuery.

For Show

```
$("#lnk").click(function () {  
$("#result").removeAttr('Style');
$("#result").attr('Style','display: inline;'); // this 
$("#result").attr('Style','display: block;'); // or this

});
```

For Hide

```
$("#lnk").click(function () {  
$("#result").removeAttr('Style');
$("#result").attr('Style','display: none;');
});
```

Comment: Hay check code i have update for your understanding its working on click of your link ( assing your link id instead of #lnk = #<yourcontrol id>)

Answer (score 0):

Here Are Some More Codez

```
 <a href="#" id="yourlink">yourlink</a>
    <form id="yourform" style="display:none;">form here.</form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#yourlink').click(function () {
            $('#yourform').css('display', 'inline');
        });
    });
    </script>
```